# What are some common purposes in using run-on sentences as a literary device?

Tags: creative-writing, technique

> Generally, this is considered grammatically incorrect, and called a
> stylistic error. There are many examples of run-on sentences used as
> literary devices in literature. However, not all long sentences are
> run-on sentences, for it is quite acceptable to combine different
> related ideas into a compound sentence. Nevertheless, without using
> appropriate punctuation rules, a compound sentence becomes a run-on
> sentence.

https://literarydevices.net/run-on-sentence/

How are they used as a literary device? What can you do with them? Unlike other literary devices like metaphors and allegory, it doesn't seem like run-on sentences can do much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that in dialog, a run on sentence can demonstrate the character's motor mouth or a lack of giving others a chance to get a word in.   If you are quoting something someone said or wrote, it is acceptable to use their incorrect grammar rather than change it to match correct grammar.  Using the "[sic]" tag at any erroneous grammar usage can denote that the poor grammar is not your choice but merely faithful replication of the quote statement.  *Sic* is Latin for "just as" although many will erroneously claim it is an acronym for "Spelled in Copy" or "Said in Context".

Comment: I don't think I'd use [sic] in fiction, though (unless in a very specific circumstance, such as a character who's a journalist working on an article).

Comment: @DM_with_secrets Again, as said, fiction it's permissible in dialog because you are capturing realistic speech.

Comment: Oh, I completely agree that using incorrect grammar in dialogue is fine - I just wouldn't mark it with [sic]